# Closing Cursor in function that returns Cursor

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I have a problem with closing Cursor in my SQLite class. When I'll close the Cursor and `SQLiteDatabase` in finally block (in `DBHelper`) then i can't read data in my other class (Can't reopen closed Cursor error) but when I do not close Cursor and `SQLiteDatabase` then i have memory leak errors.

DHHelper.java :

```
//...
public Cursor selectData(String selectVal, String tabName){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = null;
    try {
        String areaTyp = "SELECT " + selectVal + "  FROM " + tabName;
        c = db.rawQuery(areaTyp, null);
        return c;
    } finally {
        c.close();
        db.close();
    }
}
//...
```

UserMenager.java

```
    public List<UserModel> getUsersList(){
    List<UserModel> allUsers = new ArrayList<UserModel>();

    final DBHelper db = new DBHelper(appStatic.CONTEX);
    Cursor c = db.selectData("*","User");
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        while (!c.isAfterLast()) {

            allUsers.add(new UserModel(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cms_id")),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("login")),
                            c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")),
                                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("active")),
                                            c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("avatar")),
                                                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("gtoken"))));

            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();

    return allUsers;
}
```

Maybe I should do this in other way and the function that returns Cursor is a bad idea?

**EDIT:**
When i run app, i have error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed
>   object: SQLiteQuery: SELECT *  FROM User

In UserMenager.java, line

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
```

Comment: You need to fetch the data right after opening your cursor and return the data itself.

Comment: Close the cursor in `UserMenager.java'. That will fix the problem. However, it is not a very clean way of handling cleanup.

Comment: `Cursor` should be checked for `null` . and you can close it after getting data. Why don't try `Android-Room`.

Comment: xoxel - i want to make a universal functions that helps me to get data from DB. RaviH - i close Cursor and DB in 'UserMenager'. ADM - I'll add if(c!=null)c.close() but i still have error

Comment: Close the `Cursor` in a `finally` block like you do in `selectData`.

Comment: @ADM `rawQuery` never returns `null`.

Comment: Yeah in case of malformed query only .

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest returning what you want as an end result, that is an ArrayList, from the `selectData` class. You can then close the Cursor and the Database in the `selectData` method as soon as they are done with.

e.g. :-

```
public ArrayList<UserModel> selectData(String selectVal, String tabName){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); //<<<< getReadable will most likely return a writeable database anyway
    ArrayList<UserModel> rv = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor c = db.query(
            tabName,
            new String[]{selectVal},
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
    );
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        rv.add(new UserModel(
                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cms_id")),
                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("login")),
                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")),
                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("active")),
                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("avatar")),
                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("gtoken"))
        ));
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
    return rv;
}
```

Along with :-

```
public List<UserModel> getUsersList(){
    List<UserModel> allUsers = new ArrayList<UserModel>();

    final DBHelper db = new DBHelper(appStatic.CONTEX);
    return selectData("*","Users");
}
```

- Wrapping `try`/`catch` around SQLiteDatabase methods tends to cause more frustration and confusion than would otherwise be caused.
- Generally the convenience methods are recommended over the use of the `rawQuery` and `execSQL` methods (in this case `query` is the convenience method).
- Ideally **selectVal** should be a String[] of the columns rather than just a String to suit the `query` convenience method.
- As commented `getReadableDatabase` rarely gets a read only database as per

> - Create and/or open a database. This will be the same object returned by getWritableDatabase() unless some problem, such as a full disk,
>     requires the database to be opened read-only. In that case, a
>     read-only database object will be returned. If the problem is fixed, a
>     future call to getWritableDatabase() may succeed, in which case the
>     read-only database object will be closed and the read/write object
>     will be returned in the future.
>     [SQLiteDatabase getReadableDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getReadableDatabase())